# LongComparator does not work in Google Cloud Bigtable with HBase API

Tags: java, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to build some filters to filter data from Bigtable. I'm using `bigtable-hbase` drivers and HBase drivers. Actually here are my dependencies from `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
        <artifactId>bigtable-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>${bigtable.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm filtering data like this:

```
Filter filterName  = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("FName"), Bytes.toBytes("FName"),
                CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator("JOHN"));
FilterList filters = new FilterList();

filters.addFilter(filterName);

Scan scan1 = new Scan();
scan1.setFilter(filters);
```

This works ok. But then I add following to previous code:

```
Filter filterSalary = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Salary"), Bytes.toBytes("Salary"),
                CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, new LongComparator(100000));
filters.addFilter(filterSalary);
```

and it give me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.filters.UnsupportedFilterException: Unsupported filters encountered: FilterSupportStatus{isSupported=false, reason='ValueFilter must have either a BinaryComparator with any compareOp or a RegexStringComparator with an EQUAL compareOp. Found (LongComparator, GREATER_OR_EQUAL)'}
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.filters.FilterAdapter.throwIfUnsupportedFilter(FilterAdapter.java:144)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.ScanAdapter.throwIfUnsupportedScan(ScanAdapter.java:55)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.ScanAdapter.adapt(ScanAdapter.java:91)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.ScanAdapter.adapt(ScanAdapter.java:43)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable.getScanner(BigtableTable.java:247)
```

So my question is how to filter long data type? Is it hbase issue or bigtable specific?

I found this [How do you use a custom comparator with SingleColumnValueFilter on HBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577142/how-do-you-use-a-custom-comparator-with-singlecolumnvaluefilter-on-hbase) but I can't load my jars to server so it is not applicable for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleColumnValueFilter` supports the following comparators:

- `BinaryComparator`
- `BinaryPrefixComparator`
- `RegexStringComparator`.

See this link for an up-to-date list:

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences